# Use of copy constructor and overloading the assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

this is a homework question. I am working on my `Hash Table` assignment and I got stuck on the `re-hash` function. When I run the code I pasted below this error gets thrown:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429231/how-to-fix-stdlogic-error-what-basic-string-m-construct-null-not-valid) I'm still very confused on what's happening.

My best effort of producing a minimal reproducible example:

```
// {
// @note I really tried to shorten it down as much as possible, but I still need certain functions and class declarations in order for the code to run
// }

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <atomic>

class DataEntry {
private:
  std::string date;
  std::string country;
  int c_cases;
  int c_deaths;
  
public:
  DataEntry() {
    this->date = "\0";
    this->country = "\0";
    this->c_cases = 0;
    this->c_deaths = 0;
  }
  
  inline void set_date(std::string set_date) { this->date = set_date;};
  inline void set_country(std::string set_country) { this->country = set_country;};
  inline void set_c_deaths(int set_c_deaths) { this->c_deaths = set_c_deaths;};
  inline void set_c_cases(int set_c_cases) { this->c_cases = set_c_cases;};
  
  inline int get_c_cases() { return c_cases;};
  inline int get_c_deaths() { return c_deaths;};
  
  inline std::string get_date() { return date;};
  inline std::string get_country() { return country;};   
};

class CovidDB {
private:
  int size = 17;
  std::vector<std::vector<DataEntry*>> HashTable;
  
public:
  inline CovidDB() {
    HashTable.resize(size);
  }

  /** @note Copy constructor */
  CovidDB(const CovidDB& other) {
    size = other.size;
    HashTable.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      for (const auto& entry : other.HashTable[i]) {
        HashTable[i].push_back(new DataEntry(*entry));
      }
    }
  }

  inline void clear() {
    for (auto& row : HashTable) {
      for (auto& entry : row) {
        delete entry;
      }
      row.clear();
    }
    HashTable.clear();    
    HashTable.shrink_to_fit();
    ///@link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587774/destructor-not-being-called
  }

  inline ~CovidDB() { //handles memory
    clear();
  }

  /** @note Move constructor */
  CovidDB(CovidDB&& other) noexcept { 
    size = other.size;
    HashTable = std::move(other.HashTable);
    other.size = 0;
  }

  /** @note Overloaded assigment operator*/
  CovidDB& operator=(const CovidDB& other) {
  if (this == &other) {
    return *this;  // Self-assignment
  }
  // clear the data and resources
  for (auto& row : HashTable) {
    for (auto& entry : row) {
      delete entry;
    }
    row.clear();
  }
  HashTable.clear();
  HashTable.shrink_to_fit();

  // copy the data from the other object
  size = other.size;
  HashTable.resize(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (const auto& entry : other.HashTable[i]) {
      HashTable[i].push_back(new DataEntry(*entry));
    }
  }
  return *this;
 }
 void rehash();
 void display_table();
 bool add(DataEntry*);
 int re_hash_key(std::string);
 int hash(std::string);
};

int CovidDB::re_hash_key(std::string country) {
  int sum = 0;
  int count = 0;
  
  for (char c : country) {
    sum = sum + ((count + 1) * c);
    count++;
  }
  return sum % size; //returns the new hash
}

void CovidDB::rehash() {
  auto is_prime = [](int num) {
    if (num <= 1)
      return false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= std::sqrt(num); ++i) {
      if (num % i == 0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  auto find_next_prime = [&is_prime](int num) {
    while (true) {
      if (is_prime(num))
        return num;
      ++num;
    }
  };

  int new_size = size * 2;
  int new_prime_size = find_next_prime(new_size);
  size = new_prime_size; //re-assign size

  //CovidDB new_table(std::move(HashTable));//call move constructor, size 37

  std::vector<std::vector<DataEntry*>> newHashTable(size); //temp object
  newHashTable.resize(size);

  // rehash all entries from the original table to the new table
  for (std::vector<DataEntry*> row : HashTable) {
    for (DataEntry* entry : row) {
      int re_hash_i = re_hash_key(entry->get_country());
      newHashTable[re_hash_i].push_back(entry);
    }
  }

  // Clear the original table and update it with the new table
  clear(); //predefined function that I removed due to MRE 
  HashTable = newHashTable;
  std::cout << "SIZE: " << size << std::endl;
  return;
}

void CovidDB::display_table() {
  for(std::vector<DataEntry*> vec : HashTable) {
    for(DataEntry* entry : vec) {
      if (entry != nullptr) { //guard against dereferencing nullptr
        std::cout << std::flush;
        std::cout << "[Date: " << entry -> get_date() << "], "
                  << "[Country: " << entry -> get_country() << "], "
                  << "[Cases: " << entry -> get_c_cases() << "], "
                  << "[Deaths: " << entry -> get_c_deaths() << "] "
                  << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return;
}

int CovidDB::hash(std::string country) {
  int sum = 0;
  int count = 0;
  
  for (char c : country) {
    sum = sum + ((count + 1) * c);
    count++;
  }
  return sum % size; //returns the hash
}

bool CovidDB::add(DataEntry* entry) {
  int index = hash(entry->get_country());
  HashTable[index].push_back(entry);
  return true;
}

int main() {
  CovidDB base;
  DataEntry* data1 = new DataEntry();
  DataEntry* data2 = new DataEntry();

  data1->set_date("01/01/23");
  data1->set_country("Slovenia");
  data1->set_c_cases(1);
  data1->set_c_deaths(1);

  data2->set_date("02/02/23");
  data2->set_country("Slovenia");
  data2->set_c_cases(1);
  data2->set_c_deaths(1);

  // Add the entries to the CovidDB
  base.add(data1);
  base.add(data2);

  base.display_table();
  base.rehash();
  base.display_table();
}
```

The main problem is my `re-hash` method. My general idea was to:

- Get the new size `size * 2` and then `next_prime(new_size)` to get the actual size, I used a couple of lambdas to achieve that. That part works since the new size is 37 as it should be.
- I emailed my professor about my problem and she said I need to follow the [rule of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455464/is-the-rule-of-5-for-constructors-and-destructors-outdated#:%7E:text=The%20rule%20of%205%20states,must%20have%20the%20other%204.) so I made my move constructor and my overloaded operator. I don't believe the move constructor is my answer here since I don't want a copy of my original table, but I want to parse all of the existing entries, re-hash and add them to the table. I could be wrong.
- Finally, I decided to create a new object `CovidDB` and re-hash all of the. old/existing entries and push them into the new table. This sort of works but my compiler says there is no definition of the `=` and the `[]` operator if I make a new object. **If I make a new 2D `std::vecotr<std::vector<DataEntry*>>` instead of an object that works** Again I don't think that's the right solution.

The strange part to me is the fact that here:

```
bool CovidDB::add(DataEntry* entry) {
  int index = hash(entry->get_country());
  HashTable[index].push_back(entry);
  return true;
}
```

I can index my `HasHTable` object using the `[]` operator, but I can't do the same thing in my `re_hash` function. I get this error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘CovidDB’ and ‘int’)
  155 |       new_table[re_hash_i].push_back(entry);
```

for this:

```
CovidDB new_table;

  for (std::vector<DataEntry*> row : HashTable) {
    for (DataEntry* entry : row) {
      int re_hash_i = re_hash_key(entry->get_country());
      new_table[re_hash_i].push_back(entry);
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me figure out where I potentially went wrong and why would an error be thrown for the `[]` operator in one case but not the other?

I tried rubber duck debugging the code, especially the operator but came up empty-handed. My debugger throws me into the `std::vector` library.

Comment: Let me advise, don't store pointers DataEntry* in the vector, store DataEntry objects there

Comment: I would want to do the same, but storing `DataEntry*` is a requirement (also can't use `STL` and would prefer if I didn't have to make my own pointer wrapper), my professor explained it as *"extra pointer practice"*

Comment: Then use shared pointers, don't copy pointed objects.

Comment: You can use `HashTable[index]` because it is a member of `CovidDB`. In the rehash function you would need to use `new_table.HashTable[index]`.

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian `CovidDB& operator=(const CovidDB& other)` -- Your assignment operator is doing too much.  It's only purpose should be to make a copy of the original, nothing more nothing less.  Your implementation has a fatal flaw in that you erase all the data out of the `this` before you know you have the memory to allocate.  Here is a safer implementation: `CovidDB& operator=(CovidDB other) { std::swap(other.size, size); std::swap(other.HashTable, HashTable); return *this; }`. That 3 line implementation works if your copy constructor and destructor are working.

Comment: Also, it is not recommended to put "business logic" inside an assignment operator like you're doing now.  For examples, doing things like `shrink_to_fit` and other superfluous functions.  By doing this, you open the door to some of the hardest-to-find bugs in C++, and those are copy operations not making copies actual copies, but doing less or more work than neccessary.  Remember that the compiler will be calling your copy functions without you realizing it -- thus your copy/assignment functions should be the simplest of jobs and not introduce side effects.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Don't forget that copy operations may also be elided in many cases, so you shouldn't do *anything* but copy in those functions, since they may not happen at all and thus your extra fancy code that you rely on may just get removed by the compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so I fixed my rehash function and I think it somewhat works I guess, but it prints very weird characters like symbols with question marks and symbols with null inside them...does that mean I am accessing bad memory or going out of bounds or printing junk data perhaps?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Exactly -- That's why when writing a user-defined copy/assignment, you must have the mindset that you don't know when or where the code will be invoked.  The job is to make a copy, and that's it -- no "fancy stuff".  The exception to this rule maybe that the implementation of a reference-counted class that bumps up or decrements a reference count.

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian -- Implement the fixes in the answer given.  Note that the answer covers what I suggested in the comments about your assignment operator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah I saw that, I'll get on it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
// Clear the original table and update it with the new table
clear(); //predefined function that I removed due to MRE
```

This call to `clear()` calls `delete` on all the values.

You just spent a lot of time re-hashing the values and putting them into `newHashTable` but you did not remove them from the old table `HashTable` so when you call clear it goes and deletes the old values.

The solution is not to call `clear()`. You overwite the original arrays on the next line:

```
HashTable = newHashTable;
```

Which removes all the storage associaetd with `HashTable`. No other work is required.

---

Other Things to watch out for:

Using `this->` is suspect to start with. The only need to use `this->` is if you have to disambiguate a local from a member variable. This is called shadowing. The problem here is that when you forget `this->` and simply use the variable the compiler can not detect this is incorrect so introducing a source of errors. I would prefer to make sure there is no shadowing in the first place. If there is no shadowing then there is no need for `this->`

```
    this->date = "\0";
    this->country = "\0";
```

There is no need to add the `\0` into the string. The string literal `""` already contains the null terminator.

--

No need to mark these functions `inline`.

```
  inline void set_date(std::string set_date) { this->date = set_date;};
  inline void set_country(std::string set_country) { this->country = set_country;};
  inline void set_c_deaths(int set_c_deaths) { this->c_deaths = set_c_deaths;};
  inline void set_c_cases(int set_c_cases) { this->c_cases = set_c_cases;};
```

Non modifying methods should be marked `const` to let the compiler know these functions do not modify the object. Not it is quite common to pass objects by `const reference`. In this situation only methods marked as `const` can be called. So it is general good practive to make sure your object is const correct.

```
  inline int get_c_cases() { return c_cases;};
  inline int get_c_deaths() { return c_deaths;};
  
  inline std::string get_date() { return date;};
  inline std::string get_country() { return country;};   
};
```

---

Sure this works:

```
  /** @note Move constructor */
  CovidDB(CovidDB&& other) noexcept { 
    size = other.size;
    HashTable = std::move(other.HashTable);
    other.size = 0;
  }
```

But more standard is to use the initializer list:

```
  CovidDB(CovidDB&& other) noexcept
      : size(other.size)
      , HashTable(std::move(other.HashTable))
  {
    other.size = 0;
  }
```

I did it like that becuase you are not allowed to use STL. But I would take this one step further by using `std::exchange`

```
  CovidDB(CovidDB&& other) noexcept
      : size(std::exchange(other.size, 0))
      , HashTable(std::move(other.HashTable))
  {}
```

Your assignment operator is non optimal.

Sure you must be able to handle self assignment. **BUT** this is an extremely rare situation. You are pessimizing for the normal siutaiont (add an extra check) and optimizing for a situation that happens exceptionally rarely (if you have non normal situations that yes do this but don't make that assumption. Assume normal then optimize for that until you have measured). Optimize for what would be normal situations.

The standard way of doing the assignment operator is the copy and swap idiom. This has been expanded (not sure of the idiom name) to handle copy and move operations by passing by value.

```
  /** @note Overloaded assigment operator*/
  CovidDB& operator=(const CovidDB& other) {
  if (this == &other) {
    return *this;  // Self-assignment
  }
  // clear the data and resources
  for (auto& row : HashTable) {
    for (auto& entry : row) {
      delete entry;
    }
    row.clear();
  }
  HashTable.clear();
  HashTable.shrink_to_fit();

  // copy the data from the other object
  size = other.size;
  HashTable.resize(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (const auto& entry : other.HashTable[i]) {
      HashTable[i].push_back(new DataEntry(*entry));
    }
  }
  return *this;
 }
 void rehash();
 void display_table();
 bool add(DataEntry*);
 int re_hash_key(std::string);
 int hash(std::string);
};
```

// ReWrite as:

```
  /** @note Overloaded assigment operator*/
  CovidDB& operator=(CovidDB other) noexcept.   // Notice pass by value.
  {
       swap(other);                             // You will need to implement swap.
                                                // left as an excercise.
       return *this;
  }
```

Note: When you pass by value. You are either doing a `move` or a `copy` construction. The `move` is cheap. The copy may be expensive but does exactly the work you were doing in the code above. Then you simply swap the parameter and current state and let the destructor of the parameter handle clean up.

We already know a lot of primes. You don't need to go around re-computing them. Have a list of primes. You can start calculating once you have exhausted your list.

```
int CovidDB::re_hash_key(std::string country) {
  int sum = 0;
  int count = 0;
  
  for (char c : country) {
    sum = sum + ((count + 1) * c);
    count++;
  }
  return sum % size; //returns the new hash
}
```

Fix this bug:

```
  // Clear the original table and update it with the new table
  clear(); //predefined function that I removed due to MRE 
  HashTable = newHashTable;
```

Don't manually print the `DataEntry` object.

```
        std::cout << "[Date: " << entry -> get_date() << "], "
                  << "[Country: " << entry -> get_country() << "], "
                  << "[Cases: " << entry -> get_c_cases() << "], "
                  << "[Deaths: " << entry -> get_c_deaths() << "] "
                  << std::endl;
```

The `DataEntry` type should already know how to print itself.

```
        std::cout << entry << std::endl;
```

You do this by implementing the output opertator.

```
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, DataEntry const& data)
        {
            data.print(stream);   // implement the print method.
            return stream;
        }
```

That way you can get rid of unnecessary getter functions.

This is not a very good hash function. I suppose it is fine if all you are hashing are country names. But then there are only 160 (approx) contries in the world. You could pre-hash all their values :-) .

```
// Pass parameters by const reference to prevent a copy.
// Here you are making a copy of `country` each time this function
// is called but that is not required for a hash.
int CovidDB::hash(std::string country) {
  int sum = 0;
  int count = 0;
  
  for (char c : country) {
    sum = sum + ((count + 1) * c);
    count++;
  }
  return sum % size; //returns the hash
}
```

I got a [list of countries](https://www.worldometers.info/geography/alphabetical-list-of-countries/) and hashed their values. Not a very even distribution.

```
index: 0 => 13
index: 1 => 12
index: 2 => 13
index: 3 => 9
index: 4 => 8
index: 5 => 13
index: 6 => 10
index: 7 => 19        // Hope I am not in this list.
index: 8 => 11
index: 9 => 10
index: 10 => 11
index: 11 => 8
index: 12 => 12
index: 13 => 11
index: 14 => 18
index: 15 => 7
index: 16 => 10
```

Comment: Ghee, great answer, and thanks a lot! This is incredibly helpful and I am surprised someone would actually put so much time into this.

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian If you have working code it can be reviewed here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know there is a lot of hash function out there but I am restricted to this one, the professor said to use an appropriate collision handling method so I chose separate chaining to handle collisions. I think this one would be fine for low level hashing stuff

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian It will be fine for this teaching example. Just wanted to point out you should normally use a pre created one as they are harder than you would expect to write a good one.